# Auto Scrolling in Frameset

Tags: html, iframe, frameset

I m using Frame set in my UI page.
I want to make auto scrolling in frameset in vertical and horizontal both.

I want scrolling Horizontal or Vertical any one or both when it needed.
My code is :

```
<iframe
     height="120"
    name="issueQueueTabsContent"
     src="/risk/issueDetail.do?action=NextPage&frameType=content
     frameborder="0"
     scrolling="auto">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Scroll Bar will automatically appear as per the page width.

Comment: yes but i have problem in vertical scroll bar..it appear even though doesnt needed.as i have use auto, it's nt workig for vertical scroll bar.

Comment: It's not displaying ! See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/DcALk/). I think you frame has height more then 120 px.

Comment: Do you mean automatically the scrollbars appear or the content scrolls by itself?

Comment: issue is only that i just want to disapper scroll bar when it doesnt needed more.it show me gray scale instead of disappearing scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe style="overflow:auto">`